# What is the meaning of plus sign above brackets?

Tags: notation

I was wondering what the meaning of the notation $\ ( )^+ \ $is? For instance, what would be the value for $\ (x)^+ \ $for different values of x, say: $\ x=-1, x=0, x=1 \ $? Thank you in advance.

The original expression I encountered is a little complex, however I could reduce it down to something as such:

$$
\bigcup_{i \in I} \{(a+b-\sum\limits_{i=1}^k D^i)^+\}
$$

Here, the above expression represents a set and we know that any value for $D^i$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Could you give some more context? Where did you see this notation used? If I had to guess, I'd say it was the "positive part" of a real number, which returns the real number if the real number is not negative and returns $0$ if the number is negative. Among other places, this concept (but perhaps not the notation) is used in Lebesgue integration theory when going from non-negative functions to real-valued functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added what the expression was like. From the context, it makes sense to represent the "positive part" of a real number.